# Order balls by their density

Tags: measurements, density

I have a bunch of solid balls, each ball has a different diameter, a different mass and made from different material.

I can compare if one ball is heavier than another ball or if one ball is bigger than another ball, but I have no way of measuring it's mass or diameter.

What can I do to order them by their **density** ?

Comment: Mass would be proportional to weight, which you can measure. Why can't you measure their diameters?

Answer (score 1):

Dip them into a fluid; generally water; and record their speed of descend, more conveniently record the time taken to get to the bottom of the vessel containing that liquid. The time of descend is inversely proportional to their density (more the density less the time taken to get to the bottom). Arrange them in the descending order of 'time of descend' to get a ascending order of density.

Comment: What if some are less dense than water?

Comment: Use a liquid which less dense than the least dense ball.

Comment: This doesn't work. It is possible to have two balls, one with a larger radius and the other with a larger density, such that they sink at the same rate. The balls will sink at a constant rate due to the drag force of the fluid, which is proportional to the cross-sectional area of the ball ($\pi R^2$). This causes a more complicated relationship between density and sink time.

Answer (score 0):

> I can compare if one ball is heavier than another ball or if one ball is bigger than another ball, but I have no way of measuring its mass or diameter.

You could use the Archimedes principle. Try dipping the balls one by one into a very dense fluid like water. The denser the object is, the easier it will be for you to dip it. Lighter the object is, the more water would push it back up, and the harder it is for you to dip it in. This works due to the fact that the **buoyancy of an object is only dependant on its density, and invariant of its mass or volume.**

> What can I do to order them by their density?

Let me specifically address this part of the question. One neat way to order things on based on density is to put them in a jar and jiggle it. It is energetically more favourable for denser balls to come to the bottom. By jiggling, you are providing energy to the system, and helping it to reach equilibrium. So, in the end you would have a jar full of balls ordered such that the density of balls increases with its depth. It is by the same argument, that denser liquids settle at the bottom when you mix two immiscible liquids. After all, liquids are by and large a collection of many molecular balls except, they are much much smaller in size.